# Checkbox on google maps marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to have checkbox on google map marker? So user can check some markers and then display details of checked places. Thank you

Comment: Couldn't you have an image of an unchecked marker and an image of a checked marker and toggle on click?

Comment: I dont know, I believe yes. Do you have experiencies with this?

Comment: Well, I havent tried anything. I just asked wether its possible or not. I expected there will be someone with experiences with google maps API who can tell yes / no.

Comment: I suspect not, the markers are images. You'll therefore need to use images as markers, which was my original suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can toggle the image like this:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map:map,
  icon: blueIcon,
  draggable:true,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  position: parliament
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', changeIcon);


  function changeIcon() {
    if (marker.icon != redIcon) {
      marker.setIcon(redIcon);
    } else {
      marker.setIcon(blueIcon);
    }
  }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mxwxt/7/

The alternative would be to create a custom overlay which can contain markup